# ellipsis + quotes on multiline text on web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to put quotes around a piece of text. The text cannot exceed 3 lines: if it does, I want an ellipsis (and I still want the quotes). I attach what I have now. My solution uses JS: while a pure CSS solution would be ideal, possible CSS solutions seem to currently be experimental or in draft  state (e.g. [line-clamp](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow/#line-clamp)). 
Also what I don't like about this solution is that ellipsis and closing quotes characters overlap (as you can see if you run the snippet).
Suggestions?

```js
[...document.getElementsByTagName('div')].forEach(d => {
  if (d.scrollHeight > d.clientHeight) d.getElementsByClassName('onlyForClampedText')[0].className += " show";
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  //text-overflow: ellipsis;
  position: relative;
}

.onlyForClampedText {
  display: none;
}

.onlyForClampedText.show {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>"very short text"<span class="onlyForClampedText">"</span></div>
<div>"longer text longer text longer text longer text"<span class="onlyForClampedText">"</span></div>
<div>"longest text ever!! Really long, o so long! long long long and i'm not even finished yet lol, I could go on for like this forever, but i'll stop here"<span class="onlyForClampedText">"</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A pure CSS solution:

```css
span {
 max-width: 200px;
 max-height: 40px;
 overflow: hidden;
 -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
 display: -webkit-box;
 -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 position: relative;
}

div {
 position: relative;
 padding: 0 10px;
 display: inline-block;
}

div::before,
div::after {
 content: '"';
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;

}

div::before {
 left: 0;
}

div::after {
 right:0;
 bottom:0
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
    small text ever!!</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span>
    longest text ever!! Really long, o so long! long long long and i'm not even finished yet lol, I could go on for like this forever, but i'll stop here</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work if the text is longer than one line but shorter than two full lines.